# Animate the width of a GridViewColumn

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I would like to animate the width of a GridViewColumn. I can animate the GridViewColumnHeader and/or the contents of the column but neither have the desired effect. Since the GridViewColumn is not an UIElement I'm not sure how to do this. I can do something like:

```
var doubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
doubleAnimation.From = 200;
doubleAnimation.To = 300;
doubleAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
column.BeginAnimation(WidthProperty, doubleAnimation);
column.Column.Width = 300;
```

But this simply snaps the width out to 300 and the Header slowly grows out to 300.

Comment: What is `column` and what is `column.Column` and why are you not applying the animation to `column.Column`?

Comment: sorry, column is a GridViewColumnHeader and column.Column is GridViewColumn, and as I said GridViewColumn is not an UIElement (its a DependencyObject) and cannot be animated.